# install QJson in windows - 7

Tags: qt, nokia, qjson

I want to install the qjson in my windows machine. I installed the cmake and nokia qt sdk in my window 7 and use the following commands but I am getting the error..

```
C:\Program Files\qjson\build>cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
'cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation directory of cmake is not in your PATH. If you use the installer, perhaps you forgot to check "Add CMake to the system path for the current user"?